# saving data from html canvas to mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, canvas

A Meteor client code displays a canvas for user signature and option to save it to the user collection to be fetched later for inserting into future html report pages which will also need to be signed.

What is the general outline to achieve this and how to do it?

```js
//client
let imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
Meteor.call('saveImageToUser', imgData);

//server
Meteor.methods({
  'saveImageToUser': (img) => {
    Meteor.users.update(userId, {
      signature: img
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: The code looks ok. The Meteor method can be placed in lib - both client and server. Meteor does optimistic updates, updates minimongo first, and later updates the mongo in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the same thing in one of my web apps.

My html:

```
   <canvas id="simple_sketch" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

My client js :

```
var canvas = $(#simple_sketch")[0].toDataURL(); 
Meteor.call('saveImageToUser', canvas);
```

My method (remember due to meteor's user object you must save it in the `profile` object of the user.

```
'saveImageToUser' : img => {
   Meteor.users.update(userId, {
        'profile.signature' : img
   })
 }
```

Comment: Why must save it to the profile, I have saved things outside the profile object before and it works fine?

Comment: @FredJ. Only the profile object, username, email and _id of the user will get published automatically. You can write the value to any key of the user object however you will have to manually get the value back over to the client.